# Does activating the "Jaws of the Lion" DLC in a Guildmaster campaign change the requirements to unlock the scenario "It's all Just a Game"?

Tags: gloomhaven, gloomhaven-jaws-of-the-lion

In the "Guildmaster" campaign mode for Gloomhaven, there is a special scenario that is unlocked by reaching level 6 with every character and completing their personal quest. Does activating the "Jaws of the Lion" DLC and its 4 additional characters change the requirements to unlock this scenario? That is, will I also have to level each of them to 6 before I can access it?

Thanks